# Fitdistrplus unsupported distribution error

Tags: r, fitdistrplus

I am trying to verify whether my data set fits exponential or negative binomial, the function works for exponential but I get the following error using "nbinom":

```
> compare = fitdistr(A, densfun="nbinom") 

Error in fitdistr(A, densfun = "nbinom") : unsupported distribution
```

Note: I know I need more than this to verify its likely distribution.  But the issue I am having is more the fact the "nbinom" isn't functioning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're conflating the function you've used, `MASS::fitdistr()`, with `fitdistrplus::fitdist()`.

From the [documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/MASS/html/fitdistr.html), you can see `"negative binomial"` is the character string specifying this distribution in the `fitdistr` function you've used.